# Ping google about paginated sitemap django

Tags: python, django

I have `sitemap.xml` with 150k rows.
I'm using pagination, so have `sitemap.xml?p=1`, `sitemap.xml?p=2` etc.

How should I tell Google about these pages, using Django?

Or google will discover `sitemap.xml` and all pages with `p` param?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.mugo.ca/Blog/Google-Sitemaps-for-big-sites-splitting-the-sitemap-into-multiple-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using pagination with query parameters, `Django` allows you to create a [sitemap index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index) which according to the docs:

> You should create an index file if one of your sitemaps has more than
>   50,000 URLs. In this case, Django will automatically paginate the
>   sitemap, and the index will reflect that.

Inside your `URLconf` file you should have something like that (taken from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index)):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', views.index, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
    url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$', views.sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
        name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
]
```

Note that `section` keyword argument is mandatory.

Because the `sitemaps` is actually a dictionary which represents your sitemap classes (probably defined inside `sitemap.py`), `Django` will create a sitemap index file (`sitemap.xml`) which will reference the individual sitemap files (the sitemap `classes` defined in your `sitemap.py` file).

[Check here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712) how a sitemap index file looks.

Hope this helps!