# Django sitemap.xml for millions of producs

Tags: python, django, sitemap

We have a big amount of products. About 50 million items
What is the best way to generate sitemaps in Django?

At the moment we generate them the following way:

**sitemaps.py**

```
class BookSitemap1(Sitemap):
    protocol = 'https'
    changefreq = 'weekly'
    priority = 0.9

    def items(self):
        return Book.objects.all().order_by('id')[0:25000]

class BookSitemap2(Sitemap):
    protocol = 'https'
    changefreq = 'weekly'
    priority = 0.9

    def items(self):
        return Book.objects.all().order_by('id')[25000:50000]

...
```

**Urls.py**

```
sitemap_books_1 = {'books1': BookSitemap1}
sitemap_books_2 = {'books2': BookSitemap2}

...

path('books-1.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemap_books_1}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
path('books-2.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemap_books_2}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),

...
```

And so on for all our 50 million products. But this is 2000 sitemaps... We can put 50000 ulrs in each sitemap. But this will be 1000 sitemaps again

Is there any other solution to generate sitemaps in Django? Because this solutions is very inconvenient as for me

Answer (score 1):

If you return items() as a QuerySet, Django will handle the pagination for you.

```
class BookSitemap(Sitemap):
protocol = 'https'
changefreq = 'weekly'
priority = 0.9

def items(self):
    return Book.objects.all().order_by('id')
```

Then let Django sitemaps.views.index handle your index:

```
path('sitemap.xml', index, {'sitemaps': {'books': BookSitemap}}),
path('sitemap-<section>.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': {'books': BookSitemap}}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap')
```

Related: [Ping google about paginated sitemap django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292821/ping-google-about-paginated-sitemap-django)